# WPF popwindows open in the upper corner of the screen

Tags: wpf

We're creating a WPF application with VS2010 and .Net 4.0. For some reason on one computer (XP sp3) all pop windows display in the upper left corner of the screen. The pop windows I'm talking about are tooltips, menu's, combo box lists etc.

What would cause this?

Thanks,

Brad

Comment: I had the exact same problem with our tester pc but his operating system is vista. Did you find any new evidence about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think we came to the conclusion that it's a video driver problem. The application works on all other PC's.